"JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed" error while introducing WAR dependency for another WAR
I want to terminate a @MessageDriven AMQ consumer from an EAR project's code programmatically. The code of termination is like this:
private void stopJmsDelivery() {
    log.info("Stopping jms delivery");
    // this consumer can be stopped normally   
    stopJmsDelivery("jboss.as:deployment=main.ear,subdeployment=somehow-bizarre.jar,subsystem=ejb3,message-driven-bean=UnknownConsumer");
    ...
    // this one throws exception
    stopJmsDelivery("jboss.as:deployment=another.war,subsystem=ejb3,message-driven-bean=TargetConsumer");
    log.info("Stopped jms delivery");
}

private void stopJmsDelivery(String name) {
    try {
        MBeanServer s = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName n = ObjectName.getInstance(name);
        s.invoke(n, "stopDelivery", null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(STOPPING_JMS_DELIVERY_FAILED_FOR + " exception: ", e);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) { // NOSONAR catch also throwable since Exception is not enough in all cases.
        log.error(STOPPING_JMS_DELIVERY_FAILED_FOR + " throwable: ", throwable);
    }
}

This part of code is in "main.ear"."admin.war". There are several consumer classes in the same EAR and I can terminated them normally, meaning that stopDelivery() method is the right method to invoke. But the last consumer class is in another.war. If I try to stop it , NoClassDefException is thrown. However I can stop it in JBoss EAP Management Console, which means the path is correct.
Both main.ear and another.war are deployed in RedHat JBoss EAP 6.4 but separately.
main.ear
  |
   -- admin.war
another.war

To fix the NoClassDefException, in the pom.xml of module admin, I introduce the another module as dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>another</artifactId>
    <classifier>classes</classifier> <!-- so to use `another-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar` -->
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope> <!-- if put "provided", classes will not be packaged into `admin.war` and NoClassDefException -->
</dependency>

The compilation works, but when launching, this error happens:
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) - MSC000001: Failed to start service 
jboss.deployment.subunit."main.ear"."admin.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."main.ear"."admin.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "admin.war" of deployment "main.ear"
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929345566Z  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:184) [jboss-as-server-7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002.jar:7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929351032Z  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929354483Z  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929357898Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929373706Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929377514Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929381166Z Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.example.another.RestApplication com.example.admin.AdminApplication
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929384994Z  at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:206)
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929402844Z  at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929406465Z  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:177) [jboss-as-server-7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002.jar:7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002]
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929410104Z  ... 5 more
2024-06-05T11:49:58.929413220Z

How can I:

avoid putting class RestApplication into the another-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar while listing it as compiled scope dependency for admin.war
meanwhile, make sure the original RestApplication endpoint deployed in another.war works normally?

I tried to use <type>war</type>, but soon I found out that I shouldn't deploy the same WAR twice, outside and inside the main.ear.

EDIT:
As per suggested by @James, I added web.xml in the admin.war to bypass the duplicate Application class error, but saw other errors:
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632878748Z 2024-06-06 08:14:25,623 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) - MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."main.ear"."admin.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."main.ear"."admin.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "admin.war" of deployment "main.ear"
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632927864Z  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:184) [jboss-as-server-7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002.jar:7.5.23.Final-redhat-00002]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632934189Z  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632938620Z  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632943179Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632947823Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632950777Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [rt.jar:1.8.0_372]
2024-06-06T08:14:25.632953500Z Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.some-service.monitoring-metrics.ValidatorFactory is already registered
...

I will surrender and stop here, the negative impact is bigger than this so I will let operation team to stop the consumer manually from console.

Lastly:
I guess maven-assembly-plugin and descriptor-ref could generate me a jar only with the classes I want, but I don't have time to rule out every class to exclude in the jar so I give up.

How is the another-classes.jar created? It's possible you could filter it out. You might also be able to set the javax.ws.rs.Application servlet mapping in the web.xml to only enable a single REST application.

Hi @JamesR.Perkins, if you mean building tool, the classes are built by Maven. And I don't have a web.xml in the admin.war. So I have to create one?

And another.war also has a web.xml. What happens is that, if I create a new web.xml in admin module, the war file will have 2 web.xml and the another one is outside: jar tvf admin.war | grep web.xml : 658 Thu Jun 06 10:51:46 EEST 2024 WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/web.xml and 314 Wed Apr 10 22:28:58 EEST 2024 WEB-INF/web.xml. So the bigger one(that we want) is in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF and the wrong one is in WEB-INF. Which one will be used?

Sorry, the outside(smaller) web.xml is from yet another module of metrics. So not related. Maybe your approach would work, let me see

I surrender; other errors arising, duplicate service registered, I will stop here and just let operation guys use Management Console to stop the bean. I will add details in the post but I think no one could solve that; thanks @JamesR.Perkins

FWIW only one web.xml would be used and it would be the one in the admin.war/WEB-INF/web.xml. Ones from other libraries would be ignored. Assuming you're not shading the WAR. Let me know if you've got more questions :)

Thanks @JamesR.Perkins for helping. Other issues arose and I decide to stop trying now. Thanks and 2 votes up for the comments.
